# Unity HDRP Emissions - When setting over 1 nit, blue becomes progressively more purple

Tags: unity, shaders, materials, hdrp

I've been trying to use a HDRP Lit Shader material to create an intense lighting effect in a dark environment.

I'm using a texture as an emission mask which is simply a 16x16 black png split into quadrants by blue borders.

When the emission intensity is greater than 1, the emission becomes more purple than blue.

[image: Blue glow appears purple]

This is how I've configured the material

[image: Material configuration]

I'm brand new to HDRP so if anyone could shed some light into this then that would be appreciated. When I was using the unity default renderer with 2 overlapping materials it was looking fine but I was looking into doing this with shader graphs so thought it might be worth upgrading to HDRP while I was at it

Comment: Can you show us the RGB values of the blue you're using?

Comment: @DMGregory it's just RGBA (0,0,255,255). The texture I made is 0,0,255,255 on the blue borders too

Comment: I've just created a new project from the HDRP template. It doesn't happen there. I had used the HDRP Wizard to add HDRP to the project. I'm wondering if something went wrong there

Comment: Could be there's some colour grading or other post-processing set up with the wizard. Try investigating those settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the sky and fog volume object, add an exposure override if it doesn't already exist. In the exposure override, set sane min and max limits and mode to automatic histogram.

[image: Exposure config]

Hope this helps anyone else who comes across this.

Comment: Neat! What were the previous settings that broke it, for comparison? (You could add those to your question if you like)